# Normal Distribution, cant seem to reach the right answer

Tags: normal-distribution

**The scores on a statistics test are Normally distributed with parameters
mean = 80 and standard deviation = 196. Find the probability that a randomly chosen score is
no greater than 70**

My attempt,

Pr(X < 70) = Pr(z < -0.05) = 1 - Pr(z < 0.05) = 1 - 0.5199 = .4801.

The answer given in the text book is 0.2389 tho. Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: Can you explain how you got $Pr(z < -0.05)$? Not that your answer says "48% of people score below 70$, which doesn't seem to jive with "50% scored below 80".

Comment: And can you check if the problem stated standard deviation, or variance? an SD of 196 seems extremely high (esp if we assume that the test scores range from 0 to 100).

Comment: Yeah, if we use variance = 196 the book's answer seems to be correct.

Comment: Pr(z<−0.05), I did (70-80)/196. The books says sigma is 196. Must have been a miss print

Comment: yeah, using 196 as the variance gets all the other answers correct as well. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the variance is 196, then the SD is 14. The z corresponding to 70 is obtained using the standard formula (70 - mean)/SD, which in this case yields -10/14 = -0.71. Consulting the z-table, the value of 0.71 corresponds to a probability of 0.7611. Thus, the value of -0.71 corresponds to a probability of 1 - 0.7611 = 0.2389.